# Presentation-abstraction-control explanation

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking for a paper that would explain the PAC pattern well. So far all the stuff that I found is pretty sporadic. If there is an implementations of this pattern somewhere out there, that would be great too.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

An old question but since I'm looking at the same I'll post [this link "Interactive Application Architecture Patterns"](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/) that at least helped me clear everything up. Really nice write-up on a lot of MVC-like patterns and how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

Do these help?

[Jason Cai, Ranjit Kapila, and Gaurav Pal (July 2000). "HMVC: The layered pattern for developing strong client tiers". JavaWorld.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0721-hmvc.html) Retrieved 2006-05-25.

"TP" (2000). ["Is HMVC PAC? (letter to the editor)". JavaWorld.](http://web.archive.org/web/20050205080537/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2000/jw-0908-letters.html) Archived from the original on 2005-02-05. Retrieved 2006-05-25.

It might also be worth checking out the papers cited at the [Presentation-Abstraction-Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation%E2%80%93abstraction%E2%80%93control) wikipedia page